# Solving a function $f(x)$ in metric resulting $\partial_t$ and $\partial_\phi$ being Killing vector fields

Tags: general-relativity

Consider the vacuum Einstein's equation in four dimensional spacetime with a cosmological constant
$$
R_{\mu \nu}-\frac{1}{2} g_{\mu \nu} R+g_{\mu \nu} \Lambda=0 .
$$
(a) Proof that $R_{\mu \nu}=k g_{\mu \nu}$ and find out the value of $k$.

(b) Now start with an ansatz of a metric in the following form
$$
d s^2=-f(r) d t^2+\frac{1}{f(r)} d r^2+r^2\left(d \theta^2+\sin ^2 \theta d \phi^2\right),
$$
where $f(r)$ is a polynomial in $r$. Compute non zero components of the Ricci tensor $R_{\mu \nu}$ and scalar curvature $R$ of this metric.

(c) Assuming that the above ansatz is a solution of the vacuum Einstein equation with cosmological constant $\Lambda$, solve $f(r)$.

(d) Prove that $\partial_t$ and $\partial_\phi$ are Killing vector fields.

For (d), I suppose that to solve it the function $f$ should be independent with $t$ and $\phi$, but I have no idea how to derive $f(r)$ in (c). How is $f$ being solved by assumptions in (c)(and maybe with previous (a) and (b))?

Thank you!

Comment: *the function $f$ should be independent with $t$ and $\varphi$* The notation $f(r)$ indicates that $f$ depends only on $r$.

Comment: With this ansatz, Einstein’s equations become ordinary differential equations for $f$ which you can solve. Calculate $R_{\mu\nu}$ and $R$ in terms of $f$ and substitute them into Einstein’s equations.

Comment: @Ghoster I'm still a bit confused, why should we must have $R_{\mu \nu}=k g_{\mu \nu}$ in the vacuum?

Comment: Contract the first equation and see what happens.